# Bijection term usage

Tags: analysis

When we say a function is a bijection like a linear function, do we mean that the two sets are: $$\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

More generally when we write: $$f(x) = x^2$$
Do we mean that: $$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

I know this question is a litle unclear because it take care of general associations but maybe it's universal.

Comment: No, a bijection need not be a linear function, and the domain need not be $\Bbb R$. The function $f(x)=x^2$ also need not be defined from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: so we cannot say that a linear function is a bijection until we have said that the function is $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Again, your $f$ could be defined from, say, $\Bbb F_p\rightarrow \Bbb F_p$ for a prime $p$. Real numbers are not the only ones. And why should we restrict to linear functions? $f(x)=x^2$ is not linear, and you have written it yourself.

Comment: You appear to be confused.  A "bijection" is a purely set theoretic concept.  There are bijections between all sorts of sets, not just the real numbers.

Comment: For instance:  the function $x\mapsto x^2$ is a bijection on the non-negative reals but not on the entire reals (it is neither injective nor surjective on the entire reals).

Comment: And is  $f(x)=x^2$ is a bijection on the finite field $\Bbb F_2$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Since $f(x)=x^2$ is the same as the identity function on the field of 2 elements, trivially yes.

Comment: Alan, you are not Witzig.

Comment: Thanks both of you and the joke :)

Comment: @DietrichBurde If you mean to address a question to a specific person,  @ is the feature for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bijection is a function that maps each element of the domain (The first set) to a unique element of the codomain (The second set), so that every element in the codomain is hit exactly once.   In other words, a bijection is a function that lets you put a "renaming" on each element of the first set to give it a name in the second set,  matching everyone up uniquely.